Building a constrained linear sparse system
Eigen provides convenient operators similar to matlab for dense matrices. However, sparse matrices have less capabilities. For example, how would you convert the following matlab code to eigen:
function q2_ret = wrapd_solve( Acon, B, q2 )

[ nc, nv ] = size( Acon );

B2 = sparse( nv, nv );
B2(1:2:nv, 1:2:nv) = B;
B2(2:2:nv, 2:2:nv) = B;
A = [ B2 Acon'; Acon sparse( nc, nc ) ];

q = q2';
q = q(:);
q = [ q; zeros( nc, 1 ) ];

q = A \ q;

q = q(1:nv);
q2_ret = reshape( q, 2, [] )';

Details.
The function solves the problem
B x = q2
s.t. Acon x = 0

B is a sparse n x n. q2 is n x 2, two columns of coordinates (x, y). The constraint matrix couples the coordinates.
To do it in eigen, I would manually construct a list of triplets, manually calculating indices. If it was dense, I could have converted the code easily.
